# What is a type definition inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I found this in a boost directory iterator class defined in operations.hpp

```
class directory_iterator
{
    public:
      typedef path value_type;
}
```

please what does a typedef inside a class mean **generally not only in this context**

Comment: It's a type definition bound to the class scope.

Comment: Are you asking generally what `typedef` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general context, on a `template`-ed class/struct you could know the type using which it was instantiated.

```
For example:
template< typename T>
class foo 
{
public:
   typedef T value_type;
};
```

Then you can do something like

```
foo::value_type foo_T_Type;
```

Something similar for above class too

```
directory_iterator::value_type X; // for whatever the type of path is
```

Comment: sorry , but didn't really understand , can u further explain , note that I'm just following the LearnCpp website and still didn't get to the template section , I mean I don't know what template is if that helps

Comment: @MekacherAnis o_O you still didn't get to the template section and jumped into boost's `directory_iterator` ? Probably not a good choice. 
As to further explanation, this typedef style you will find all over in C++ standard template library, boost libraries, Its a generic and policy based design approach, commonly used. My example is not the only one use.

Comment: it's just a fun project that takes a directory and sorts its members in folders according to their extension . and I'm in chapter 13 so the next one would be about the templates